# What is the meaning of "hazte cargo de ella"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

> De modo que no jodas, concluyó: Anda, despiértala,
>   pídele perdón, y hazte cargo de ella de una vez. Nadie merece ser más feliz que
>   ustedes. (Memorias de mis putas tristes, Garcia Marquez)

Here in this paragraph I have two questions. First, I wonder if the author had any sexual inference by "no jodas" or does it in Spanish mean "fucking around" and "procrastinating" as Grossman has translated in her English translation?

Second, I wonder what is the meaning of "hazte cargo de ella" in this context? Does it mean "to own" as Grossman has used? Or does it mean "simply have sex with her"?

> So stop fucking around, she concluded: Go on, wake her, beg her
>   pardon, and take charge of her once and for all. Nobody deserves to be happier than you two. (Grossman, Memories of my melancholy whores).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of the expressions has sexual connotations.

The first one (*no jodas*) is properly translated as "stop fucking around". Other milder versions of the expression are:

- No [fastidies](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HfHlnC4).
- No [incordies](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LJSUXKn).

In this case, the verb *[joder](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MVjNCIs)* is used in its 5th meaning according to the DLE:

> 5. tr. malson. Molestar o fastidiar a alguien. U. t. c. intr.

The expression is usually used as "no me jodas", indicating the object of the action (the person being annoyed). If you omit the direct object, the person is just annoying (no one in particular, just annoying).

The second one (*hazte cargo de ella*) can also be written as *encárgate de ella* (take care of her), being *[encargarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=F0p6rb4)*:

> 1. tr. Encomendar, poner algo al cuidado de alguien. U. t. c. prnl.

And *[encomendar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=F8Fvxoa)*:

> 1. tr. Encargar a alguien que haga algo o que cuide de algo o de alguien.

So she is just asking him to take care of the well-being of the other woman. There is no obscure meaning (there could be) in this case.

Comment: I agree with Carlos on all counts. I'd just add that "hacerse cargo de alguien/algo" may mean -- and this might be the case here -- something like "Assume your responsibility and take care of her once and for all." The interlocutor is already responsible for her and is merely reminded of the responsibility he holds (and advised not to evade it).

Comment: I also agree and add something :) "_No jodas_" used without the direct object is also often used to express surprise, given something just seen or heard... although in that case I'd write it with exclamation and/or interrogation marks: "_¡No jodas!_".

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de ver la segunda pregunta puede ser:

"Hazte cargo de ella" es una expresión habitual en español para hacer referencia a "ser responsable de ella".

Por ejemplo, cuando un niño recibe una mascota de regalo de sus padres. éstos le dirán "hazte cargo de ella", o bien "se responsable con ella".

Saludos.